# PyCharm highlights lines of importing modules

Tags: python, import, module, pycharm, warnings

**PyCharm** **highlights** lines of **importing** modules (only made by me modules) with red wavy line and give **warning** "Unresolved reference 'module_name'". But they all (my modules) are located in common package "main". In spite of this unexpected behavior, code is **executed correctly**.

On linked picture, you can see code/project tree/warning

How to avoid this warnings?

[***picture*** of code; project tree; warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxooq.png)

Comment: Please add your code, project tree and warnings as text, not as an image.

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [Please add a Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that illustrates your issue.

Answer (score 2):

On the left pane, you should define where the root directory of your code it is.

Go to relevant directory (on left pane), right click on the mouse, on bottom you have **mark directory as** and then select "source root".

You may select various roots, in case of documentation (the python building scripts), testing, or also some utility tools. But you should explicitly tell PyCharm were the main directory of the project it is.