# How to force the PyCharm IDE to recognize the packages installed in my python environment during development inside the IDE itself?

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, conda

I am familiar with Conda, pip, envs and PyCharm and of course see this question before [PyCharm doesn't recognize installed module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235376/pycharm-doesnt-recognise-installed-module) -- which has been useless to me so far. PyCharm says that my library `uutils` is not installed but when I go to the terminal and import it works just fine (from my terminal):

```
(iit-term-synthesis) brandomiranda~ ❯ python
Python 3.9.12 (main, Jun  1 2022, 06:36:29)
[Clang 12.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import uutils
>>> uutils.helloworld()

hello from uutils __init__.py in:
<module 'uutils' from '/Users/brandomiranda/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/__init__.py'>

>>>
```

In PyCharm's terminal:

```
(iit-term-synthesis) brandomiranda~/ultimate-utils ❯ python
Python 3.9.12 (main, Jun  1 2022, 06:36:29) 
[Clang 12.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import uutils
>>> uutils.helloworld()

hello from uutils __init__.py in:
<module 'uutils' from '/Users/brandomiranda/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/__init__.py'>

>>>
```

from PyCharm's console:

```
/Users/brandomiranda/miniconda/envs/iit-term-synthesis/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py --mode=client --host=127.0.0.1 --port=55783 
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
sys.path.extend(['/Users/brandomiranda/ultimate-utils', '/Users/brandomiranda/iit-term-synthesis', '/Users/brandomiranda/proverbot9001', '/Users/brandomiranda/ultimate-utils', '/Users/brandomiranda/pycoq', '/Users/brandomiranda/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src', '/Users/brandomiranda/iit-term-synthesis', '/Users/brandomiranda/iit-term-synthesis/iit-term-synthesis-src', '/Users/brandomiranda/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src', '/Users/brandomiranda/ultimate-utils'])
Python 3.9.12 (main, Jun  1 2022, 06:36:29) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
PyDev console: using IPython 8.4.0
Python 3.9.12 (main, Jun  1 2022, 06:36:29) 
[Clang 12.0.0 ] on darwin
import uutils
uutils.helloworld()
hello from uutils __init__.py in:
<module 'uutils' from '/Users/brandomiranda/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/__init__.py'>
```

from debugger works fine:

```
/Users/brandomiranda/miniconda/envs/iit-term-synthesis/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --cmd-line --multiprocess --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 55789 --file /Users/brandomiranda/iit-term-synthesis/iit-term-synthesis-src/mains/main_debug_lf.py 
Connected to pydev debugger (build 222.3345.131)
import uutils
Python 3.9.12 (main, Jun  1 2022, 06:36:29) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
PyDev console: using IPython 8.4.0
uutils.helloworld()
hello from uutils __init__.py in:
<module 'uutils' from '/Users/brandomiranda/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/__init__.py'>
```

However, when one looks at the IDE it underlines `uutils` in red and thus does not autocomplete and do all the nice features of PyCharm:

[image]

However, the demo right before I just showed does import it if I run it! It's bizzare. Of course I've set up the PyCharm interpreter (and in fact removed it multiple times and re-installed everything with brand new envs and it doesn't work!):

[image]

I def have the right Conda env:

[image]

I've tried removing it and re-installing the env from:

- the terminal
- from within PyCharm

I've also tried removing all the `.idea` folders and started from scratch e.g. as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73336726/1601580

I've also:

- uninstalled PyCharm and re-installed it
- updated PyCharm

I can also see the projects are in pip list:

```
(iit-term-synthesis) brandomiranda~ ❯ pip list
Package                 Version      Editable project location
----------------------- ------------ --------------------------------------------------------------
absl-py                 1.2.0
aiofile                 3.8.1
aiohttp                 3.8.1
aiosignal               1.2.0
appnope                 0.1.3
astroid                 2.11.7
asttokens               2.0.7
async-timeout           4.0.2
attrs                   22.1.0
backcall                0.2.0
cachetools              5.2.0
caio                    0.9.7
certifi                 2022.6.15
charset-normalizer      2.1.0
click                   8.1.3
cycler                  0.11.0
dataclasses-json        0.5.7
datasets                2.4.0
debugpy                 1.6.2
decorator               5.1.1
dill                    0.3.5.1
docker-pycreds          0.4.0
entrypoints             0.4
executing               0.9.1
filelock                3.8.0
fonttools               4.34.4
frozenlist              1.3.1
fsspec                  2022.7.1
gitdb                   4.0.9
GitPython               3.1.27
google-auth             2.10.0
google-auth-oauthlib    0.4.6
grpcio                  1.47.0
huggingface-hub         0.8.1
idna                    3.3
iit-term-synthesis      0.0.1        /Users/brandomiranda/iit-term-synthesis/iit-term-synthesis-src
importlib-metadata      4.12.0
iniconfig               1.1.1
ipykernel               6.15.1
ipython                 8.4.0
isort                   5.10.1
jedi                    0.18.1
joblib                  1.1.0
jupyter-client          7.3.4
jupyter-core            4.11.1
kiwisolver              1.4.4
lark-parser             0.12.0
lazy-object-proxy       1.7.1
Markdown                3.4.1
MarkupSafe              2.1.1
marshmallow             3.17.0
marshmallow-enum        1.5.1
matplotlib              3.5.3
matplotlib-inline       0.1.3
mccabe                  0.7.0
multidict               6.0.2
multiprocess            0.70.13
mypy-extensions         0.4.3
nest-asyncio            1.5.5
networkx                2.8.5
numpy                   1.23.1
oauthlib                3.2.0
packaging               21.3
pandas                  1.4.3
parso                   0.8.3
pathos                  0.2.9
pathtools               0.1.2
pexpect                 4.8.0
pickleshare             0.7.5
Pillow                  9.2.0
pip                     22.1.2
platformdirs            2.5.2
plotly                  5.10.0
pluggy                  1.0.0
pox                     0.3.1
ppft                    1.7.6.5
progressbar2            4.0.0
promise                 2.3
prompt-toolkit          3.0.30
protobuf                3.19.4
psutil                  5.9.1
ptyprocess              0.7.0
pure-eval               0.2.2
py                      1.11.0
py-cpuinfo              8.0.0
pyarrow                 9.0.0
pyasn1                  0.4.8
pyasn1-modules          0.2.8
pycoq                   0.0.1a1.dev3 /Users/brandomiranda/pycoq
Pygments                2.12.0
pylint                  2.14.5
pyparsing               3.0.9
pytest                  7.1.2
pytest-benchmark        3.4.1
python-dateutil         2.8.2
python-utils            3.3.3
pytoolconfig            1.2.2
pytz                    2022.2
PyYAML                  6.0
pyzmq                   23.2.1
regex                   2022.7.25
requests                2.28.1
requests-oauthlib       1.3.1
responses               0.18.0
rope                    1.3.0
rsa                     4.9
scikit-learn            1.1.2
scipy                   1.9.0
sentry-sdk              1.9.4
setproctitle            1.3.2
setuptools              61.2.0
sexpdata                0.0.3
shortuuid               1.0.9
six                     1.16.0
smmap                   5.0.0
stack-data              0.3.0
strace-parser           0.2.0
tenacity                8.0.1
tensorboard             2.10.0
tensorboard-data-server 0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit  1.8.1
threadpoolctl           3.1.0
tokenizers              0.12.1
tomli                   2.0.1
tomlkit                 0.11.3
torch                   1.9.1
torchaudio              0.9.1
torchtext               0.10.1
torchvision             0.10.1
tornado                 6.2
tqdm                    4.64.0
traitlets               5.3.0
transformers            4.21.1
typing_extensions       4.3.0
typing-inspect          0.7.1
ultimate-utils          0.5.5        /Users/brandomiranda/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src
urllib3                 1.26.11
wandb                   0.13.1
wcwidth                 0.2.5
Werkzeug                2.2.2
wheel                   0.37.1
wrapt                   1.14.1
xxhash                  3.0.0
yarl                    1.8.1
zipp                    3.8.1
(iit-term-synthesis) brandomiranda~ ❯ conda list
# packages in environment at /Users/brandomiranda/miniconda/envs/iit-term-synthesis:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
absl-py                   1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
aiofile                   3.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
aiohttp                   3.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
aiosignal                 1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
appnope                   0.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
astroid                   2.11.7                   pypi_0    pypi
asttokens                 2.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi
async-timeout             4.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     22.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
backcall                  0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ca-certificates           2022.07.19           hecd8cb5_0
cachetools                5.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
caio                      0.9.7                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2022.6.15        py39hecd8cb5_0
charset-normalizer        2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
click                     8.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
cycler                    0.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
dataclasses-json          0.5.7                    pypi_0    pypi
datasets                  2.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
debugpy                   1.6.2                    pypi_0    pypi
decorator                 5.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
dill                      0.3.5.1                  pypi_0    pypi
docker-pycreds            0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
entrypoints               0.4                      pypi_0    pypi
executing                 0.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
filelock                  3.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
fonttools                 4.34.4                   pypi_0    pypi
frozenlist                1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
fsspec                    2022.7.1                 pypi_0    pypi
gitdb                     4.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
gitpython                 3.1.27                   pypi_0    pypi
google-auth               2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.6                    pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.47.0                   pypi_0    pypi
huggingface-hub           0.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
idna                      3.3                      pypi_0    pypi
iit-term-synthesis        0.0.1                     dev_0    <develop>
importlib-metadata        4.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
iniconfig                 1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
ipykernel                 6.15.1                   pypi_0    pypi
ipython                   8.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
isort                     5.10.1                   pypi_0    pypi
jedi                      0.18.1                   pypi_0    pypi
joblib                    1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-client            7.3.4                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-core              4.11.1                   pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi
lark-parser               0.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
lazy-object-proxy         1.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
libcxx                    12.0.0               h2f01273_0
libffi                    3.3                  hb1e8313_2
markdown                  3.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                2.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
marshmallow               3.17.0                   pypi_0    pypi
marshmallow-enum          1.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib                3.5.3                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib-inline         0.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
mccabe                    0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
multidict                 6.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
multiprocess              0.70.13                  pypi_0    pypi
mypy-extensions           0.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
ncurses                   6.3                  hca72f7f_3
nest-asyncio              1.5.5                    pypi_0    pypi
networkx                  2.8.5                    pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.23.1                   pypi_0    pypi
oauthlib                  3.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   1.1.1q               hca72f7f_0
packaging                 21.3                     pypi_0    pypi
pandas                    1.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
parso                     0.8.3                    pypi_0    pypi
pathos                    0.2.9                    pypi_0    pypi
pathtools                 0.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pexpect                   4.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pickleshare               0.7.5                    pypi_0    pypi
pillow                    9.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       22.1.2           py39hecd8cb5_0
platformdirs              2.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
plotly                    5.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pluggy                    1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pox                       0.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
ppft                      1.7.6.5                  pypi_0    pypi
progressbar2              4.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
promise                   2.3                      pypi_0    pypi
prompt-toolkit            3.0.30                   pypi_0    pypi
protobuf                  3.19.4                   pypi_0    pypi
psutil                    5.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
ptyprocess                0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pure-eval                 0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
py                        1.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
py-cpuinfo                8.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyarrow                   9.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1                    0.4.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pycoq                     0.0.1a1.dev3             pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pylint                    2.14.5                   pypi_0    pypi
pyparsing                 3.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
pytest                    7.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pytest-benchmark          3.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.9.12               hdfd78df_1
python-dateutil           2.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
python-utils              3.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
pytoolconfig              1.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pytz                      2022.2                   pypi_0    pypi
pyyaml                    6.0                      pypi_0    pypi
pyzmq                     23.2.1                   pypi_0    pypi
readline                  8.1.2                hca72f7f_1
regex                     2022.7.25                pypi_0    pypi
requests                  2.28.1                   pypi_0    pypi
requests-oauthlib         1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
responses                 0.18.0                   pypi_0    pypi
rope                      1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
rsa                       4.9                      pypi_0    pypi
scikit-learn              1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
sentry-sdk                1.9.4                    pypi_0    pypi
setproctitle              1.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                61.2.0           py39hecd8cb5_0
sexpdata                  0.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
shortuuid                 1.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
six                       1.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
smmap                     5.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.39.2               h707629a_0
stack-data                0.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
strace-parser             0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tenacity                  8.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard               2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-data-server   0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
threadpoolctl             3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.12               h5d9f67b_0
tokenizers                0.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tomli                     2.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tomlkit                   0.11.3                   pypi_0    pypi
torch                     1.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
torchaudio                0.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
torchtext                 0.10.1                   pypi_0    pypi
torchvision               0.10.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tornado                   6.2                      pypi_0    pypi
tqdm                      4.64.0                   pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 5.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
transformers              4.21.1                   pypi_0    pypi
typing-extensions         4.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
typing-inspect            0.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tzdata                    2022a                hda174b7_0
ultimate-utils            0.5.5                     dev_0    <develop>
urllib3                   1.26.11                  pypi_0    pypi
wandb                     0.13.1                   pypi_0    pypi
wcwidth                   0.2.5                    pypi_0    pypi
werkzeug                  2.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
wrapt                     1.14.1                   pypi_0    pypi
xxhash                    3.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
xz                        5.2.5                hca72f7f_1
yarl                      1.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
zipp                      3.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
zlib                      1.2.12               h4dc903c_2
(iit-term-synthesis) brandomiranda~ ❯
```

I've tried in the past doing `conda develop .` to them to but that failed. I will try that again in a bit.

At this point I don't know what else to do. Any suggestions would be helpful.

cross:

- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/7122004478738-How-to-force-pycharm-recognize-the-packages-installed-in-my-python-environment-
- https://www.reddit.com/r/pycharm/comments/wmvnh7/how_to_force_the_pycharm_ide_to_recognize_the/
- https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-do-I-force-the-PyCharm-IDE-to-recognize-the-packages-installed-in-my-Python-environment-during-development-inside-the-IDE-itself

Comment: `uutils` is your local library package named `ultimate-utils`? *The question should be updated to include the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.*

Comment: @aaron if you know a way to produce the minimal state of pycharm's ide let me know. That way I can systematically add one thing at a time until it always highlights my import statements properly.

Comment: I mean share `ultimate-utils`. That's code right? We can't reproduce without your local library. Or can you reproduce with a public library?

Comment: You should include in all your snippets: `print(os.getcwd())` and `print(sys.path)`. Looking at module path, it seems it's located under *ultimate-utils-proj-src* subdir in your current project dir, and **not** installed by *PIP*. Also when working with shell commands (*python*, *pip*) use full paths to be sure in case you have multiple versions installed / configured, or at least *which* on them.

Comment: @CharlieParker Please stop abusing SO bounty system

Comment: Please update to show what your `PyCharm Project Structure` looks like similar to [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-project-structure.html). Where is `uutils` located relative to your context root? What directory were you in when you imported on the command line?

Answer (score 2):

This thread deserves some **historical depth**.

The first reported instance of the bug (I've found) is [PY-976](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-976/Unresolved-references-to-editable-packages-pip-install-e-after-installing-before-restart-due-to-egg-link-and-new-entries-in), reported on **13th May 2010**. (Just seeing a bug ticket with a 3 digit serial number is amazing; at the time of this writing **September 2022** the current ticket number on the JetBrains' bug tracker is [PY-56446](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-56446/Defining-properties-in-a-specific-way-causes-false-positive-unexpected-argument)). The original PY-976 report has nearly two dozen duplicates, half a dozen linked posts, and the bug was fixed but also regressed in several PyCharm releases over the years (see the timeline).

The IDE's [development install](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#working-in-development-mode) bugs sometimes also come with different symptoms, e.g. see JetBrains bug tracker [PY-43784](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-43784/Python-egg-link-packages-not-correctly-analyzed) but also here on SO [Q 69379983](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69379983) (with the entire package failing to be recognized by the [Project Tool Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-tool-window.html)). This bug was related because it also happened with development installs, and the workaround was also having to manually set the project structure.

Quoting the OP's self-answer:

> btw, I am really unsatisfied with this solution. I really want my project/folders to be where ever I want, not where PyCharm wants.

Aren't we all? Last time I was hit by this bug (sometime in the 2019 or 2020 regressions) I lost 2 days until I came to terms with the fact that it wasn't my fault and there wasn't much I could do except using a workaround.

> How can we fix this?

You can't. It's a bug. My solution has been postponing IDE updates until I'm sure I won't be hit by a workflow breaking bug in the next release. I'm currently on PyCharm 2022.1 Pro, I'll upgrade to 2022.2 only when 2022.3 is released. That way if I run into a bug like this at least I can update a second time and skip a problematic release.

**End note:**

If you think about it the workaround doesn't make much sense, the installed package can differ from the sources. And you're setting 2 instances of the same package on the PYTHONPATH (one in the venv the other in the sources). The workaround "Add Content Root" consists of having the IDE use the installed package at run time, but setting the sources directory to have the IDE produce linter warnings. (This is a linter/inspections subsystem bug).

Answer (score 1):

Some people have reported this issue on the web but it seems like there is no response. Possible solutions:

- downgrade your PyCharm to version 2020.2.4. [How to change Pycharm version](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/)
- > On the left pane, you should define where the root directory of your code it is. Go to relevant directory (on left pane), right click on the mouse, on bottom you have mark directory as and then select "source root". [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63073341/pycharm-highlights-lines-of-importing-modules)
- Marking the `src` folder as source's root
- > see `File` | `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Editor` | `File Types`. Look for your file name mapped to the **Text** type or to the **Auto-detect file type by content** type. Remove the incorrect mapping and it will fix the issue. If you still can't find the wrong mapping in the IDE settings, locate the `options/filetypes.xml` file in the [Configuration directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory). Close the IDE and either edit this file to remove the incorrect mapping or delete this file to reset all the file types to the defaults.
- Reimport all modules again, but this time select an option to download all sources/dependencies before confirming and restarting PyCharm
- `File` | `Manage IDE Settings` | `Restore Default Settings`

Answer (score 1):

I have found that python doesn't index the full path.  If `foo` is the root of the python path, and the path to `uutils` relative to foo is `where/to/look/for' then I will first try

```
from where.to.look.for import uutils
```

Answer (score 1):

You likely just have your PyCharm `content root` configured incorrectly.

`Settings | Project | Project Structure` -> Navigate to / Select the directory that **contains** the `uutils` directory -> `Add Content Root`

This will add the directory to your path, which should allow PyCharm to 'see' the directory.

I can't say what your directory structure 'should' look like as that's mostly philosophical and depends on your code/codebase.

Comment: @CharlieParker this post is just the workaround (and it's incomplete in some cases) the complete answer is the one given by CristiFati.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the module path (from the snippets): 
*/Users/brandomiranda/ultimate-utils/**ultimate-utils-proj-src**/uutils/__init__.py*, it's clear the module is **not installed** (in *Python*'s *site-packages*), but located in project root *dir*, under *ultimate-utils-proj-src* (as stated in a comment, this can be an effect of actually being installed with `pip --editable` ([[PyPA.SetupTool]: Development Mode (a.k.a. “Editable Installs”)](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html#development-mode-a-k-a-editable-installs)) - fact that was not specified in the question). That folder is in ***${PYTHONPATH}*** (at least for some interpreter instances).

This is exactly as described in [[SO]: PyCharm doesn't recognize installed module (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73363599/4788546) item ***#2.*** (possibly mixed with ***#1.***).

[[SO]: How PyCharm imports differently than system command prompt (Windows) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55083046/4788546) proposes a fix, by adding that folder as *content root* in the *PyCharm* project. 
However (depending on the *uutils* module, how frequent is it used by other projects, other environmental settings), there are other possible fixes:

- `pip install` the module
- Add its path to *${PYTHONPATH}* (globally, per user, per terminal, ...)
- Manually (from code) add its path to *sys.path*, but that's neither one of recommended, scalable, nice, ...

As I stated in one of the comments, looking at *sys.path* and *os.getcwd()* (and *sys.executable*) can save a tremendous amount of time and frustration when running into with this kind of problems.

Comment: I need it in editable mode pip install -e .

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked after a 1 week long back and forward with the support team at JetBrains (with Sergey Karpov, reqyest #4225123):

1. make a new pycharm project with `File | New Project`
2. I did not attach it to my current open project once the pop up window appeared, I made a new window.
3. I git cloned the projects from scratch in that directory.
4. I marked pythonProject1 as `Sources Root`
5. Then git repo inside of it as `Sources Root`
6. Then for each git repo, every source python package as `Source Root`

Attacked screen shot to clarify 5 & 6. Then the pycharm language server started using my editable installs properly and underlining things properly.

Idk if this works for other configurations e.g. I always have issues when connecting pycharm to remote things e.g. Docker containers or Remote servers/HPCs. If you know how to fix this same issue there let me know.

---

btw, I am really unsatisfied with this solution. I really want my project/folders to be where ever I want, not where pycharm wants. How can we fix this?

[image]

Comment: fyi: btw, I am really unsatisfied with this solution. I really want my project/folders to be where ever I want, not where pycharm wants. How can we fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I installed my working package in development mode like this:

```
pip install -e .
```

Is your problem still there when you install it without the `-e`?

If not read this [Jetbrain issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-45708#Workaround) and the according workaround.  This did the trick for me:

[image]